# Glassfish (2.1) JSF (1.2) setting 404 page

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, http-status-code-404

I've inherited a JSF 1.2 app that is running on glassfish 2.1.
Currently, if a page is not found, a static HTML page is displayed. I want to change the location of this HTML page, but I'm not sure where I specify the page location to show if a page is not found. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just an update. I've already modified my domain.xml and set the virtual-server property to <property name="send-error_1" value="path=/404.html reason=Resource_not_found code=404"/> this does not work, I get taken to the browser HTTP 404 Not Found page.

Comment: I also have my web.xml set up with
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.html</location>
    </error-page>

Comment: This issue is unrelated to JSF, instead with GF and Web Applications.

Answer (score 0):

You looked at the right places. The virtual-server property changes the X0X pages for the complete instance. The error-page for a single application. Both should work. 
If not, you might hit a bug. Asking in the users mailinglist would be a good idea then ...
http://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/users/archive

- M

Comment: We are using OpenCMS and wanted it to go to a page in OpenCMS, but for some reason it is going to the static page we have. Rather that spend too much time on it, I just modified out static page to do a redirect, and that does the trick.